# Xampp won't load in Android Browser

Tags: android, xampp

First of all, this isn't my first time using xampp to connect my android app to mysql. It used to work fine before when I open xampp in my phone using my IP Address. But now it won't load, it's always "Unable to reach network".  I can open it in my PC and both device are in the same WIFI network. I also tried adding a new rule in my firewall for httpd.exe but it still won't load. I don't know if this is because my ISP change my internet modem because the old one broke down but if it is, Can someone tell me how to configure it? I hope someone could help me

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Xampp ports are not allowed in my Firewall, sorry for my dumb mistake.